# Equivalent of `web3.eth.accounts[x]` in web3 1.0.0-beta.27

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I have testrpc initialised:

`testrpc -a 10`

And have connected via http from a node command line using web3 version 1.0.0-beta.27:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
```

I'd like to be able to access the 3rd of the accounts initialised in testrpc using web3. In version 0.x.x I'd use `web3.eth.accounts[3]`. In the  beta it seems that the process will change ([docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/web3js/1.0/web3js.pdf)) to use a `getAccounts` function.

Here's what I've attempted with the console output - I can see the list of accounts but can't seem to access them - there's possibly something simple I'm missing?

```
> web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)[3]
undefined
> null [ '0xEc9F5cEF462dc92C1A04758b93Bf940142dD9AB8',
  '0xF1EB9C3FCa1e8e43597eB9Ec9204b57811317483',
  '0xCf7127dAc175E7d0cB5AB989DDCBa993Af5CC257',
  '0xddAB30A0b405FDe916060dAb961A8939bcB0292c',
  '0x76721db21AA265453BD17FCE53637D5A621AD434',
  '0x8a2D213434034DbE47501DEC88Cf2c74eaF7cA78',
  '0xBa523A69318A831F7463C88CF2e96143e4643Ae1',
  '0xDE8f72ad2221f5dc188cC2c780E256Ce0f8e16A4',
  '0x9E10ec8A473a15b37D8EcdD65d3f9c4f04f5eD83',
  '0xedc486961d350d26F8Df6D9b5CD5451Dc4ebCAc5' ]


> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)[3]
undefined
> [ '0xEc9F5cEF462dc92C1A04758b93Bf940142dD9AB8',
  '0xF1EB9C3FCa1e8e43597eB9Ec9204b57811317483',
  '0xCf7127dAc175E7d0cB5AB989DDCBa993Af5CC257',
  '0xddAB30A0b405FDe916060dAb961A8939bcB0292c',
  '0x76721db21AA265453BD17FCE53637D5A621AD434',
  '0x8a2D213434034DbE47501DEC88Cf2c74eaF7cA78',
  '0xBa523A69318A831F7463C88CF2e96143e4643Ae1',
  '0xDE8f72ad2221f5dc188cC2c780E256Ce0f8e16A4',
  '0x9E10ec8A473a15b37D8EcdD65d3f9c4f04f5eD83',
  '0xedc486961d350d26F8Df6D9b5CD5451Dc4ebCAc5' ]
```

I've tried a few variants of the above - the output I'm aiming for is `'OxddAB...'`

**What command in web3 v1.0.0-beta.27 reproduces the behaviour of `web.eth.accounts[3]` in web3 v 0.x.x?**

I'd like to understand the reason for the proposed change, in case anyone here knows or can provide a link...

**Edit** - Managed to do it like this:

```
var a=web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)
a._rejectionHandler0[3]
```

but it seems clunky/incorrect - can anyone improve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you write `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)[3]` the result of the `getAccounts()` is being passed in to `console.log` which is a function. The `[3]` bit is then being tacked on to the end which is meaningless.

```
const get3rdAccount = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  return accounts[3]
}
```

will do what you need. (or you can also use the callback approach as outlined by @Marez if you prefer)

Answer (score 3):

`web3.eth.getAccounts` takes a callback function as an argument, and that callback function is called with array of accounts as one of the arguments.

The code you're looking for is:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
    if(error != null)
        console.log("Couldn't get accounts');

    console.log(result); //logs all accounts
    console.log(result[3]); //logs 3rd account
});
```

Comment: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
  console.log(accounts)
}`
appears to work just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marez's answer:

```
a=[]
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error,data){for (x in data){a.push(data[x])}})
```

then

```
> a[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using Ganache-cli and want to see the particular address in truffle console then you can use `web3.eth.getAccounts().then((f) => f[3])`
It will print the address at index 3 provided by ganache.